# How to stop WCF Service project from being hosted automatically while debugging

Tags: asp.net, wcf, hosting, wcf-hosting

I have Asp.Net solution that contains few WCF Service projects. Every time i run the application in debug mode, i can see that my services being hosted on ASP.Net Development Server. I just have single project in the start up.

Is there a way i can avoid this without removing these WCF Service projects from the solution?

To reproduce the situation. Create one ASP.Net project and add several WCF Service projects. Press F5 and you will see the WCF service projects being hosted on local development server.

This is what i have tried so far:

1) `Project->Properties->Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application.` I selected this option but it still hosts the service.

2) Unchecked `ASP.NET in Debuggers` selection. It still hosts the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try right click the WCF project and go to the **WCF Options** tab.

[image]

Uncheck the **Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in same solution.**

Comment: I dont see WCF Options. May be because i am using VS 2008?

Comment: Saw this solution just after I found it myself. Upvote to make it more visible as I saw the other answer and that was what lead me to finding this.

Comment: Just as a note for this solution. It solved my problem, but my symptoms were such that when I attached to the process (in this case, I was attaching to w3wp.exe), the service actually stopped working. I would get an error that the service was unavailable when attempting to make simple call via the WCFTestClient. Unchecking this checkbox solved that for me.